# Why isn't this timing of program right?

Tags: python

```
start = time.time()

process_file(builder_configs.data_directory_id)

end = time.time()

print("Time spent: ", str(timedelta(minutes=(end - start))))
```

At the end of the running the program, it shows:

```
Time spent:  1 day, 12:12:41.348290
```

This is totally wrong. It runs and ended within at most 1 hour, but it shows 1 day? How to interpret this?

Comment: Time.time() returns seconds, not minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Miloslaw Smyk commented, you want to set the seconds, not the minutes because `time.time()` measures seconds.  You can fix this by replacing the last line with this:

```py
print("Time spent: ", str(timedelta(seconds=(end - start))))
```

Comment: What about if I want the time units is minutes, not seconds?

Comment: You can build a function which returns time.time()/60. However time.time() is not a good way to measure performance. You can't rely on a time.time(). Have a look at timeit.